# Prevent wordpress from changing htaccess

Tags: wordpress

I need to use wordpress/woocommerce functions on codeigniter.  I've tried the Woocommerce Rest Api and it is extremely slow.  So for an alternative i've copied wordpress/woocommerce to codeigniter upload folder.  In the `index.php` in codeigniter i've added

```
  require_once('/home/sites/example.co.uk/public_html/retail/uploads/wordpress/wp-load.php');
        require_once('/home/sites/example.co.uk/public_html/retail/uploads/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Which is fine, i can now use wordpress functions but my codeigniter urls have been changed.  I've removed the .htaccess from the Wordpress folder and urls are still changed.  How do i solve?

Comment: How about making the .htaccess read only and just saving a blank file?

Comment: I tried that i changed the file permissions for the wordpress .htaccess to read only and a blank file and the links still change.

Comment: What are the permissions you have on `.htaccess` as it sits, and who are the owner and group owner of the file?

Comment: the permissions are 444 and the owner/group is `784005 783684`, which is the same for every file.

Comment: group ownership looks wrong (off the top of my head), let me log in and check

Comment: should be 644 as a rule, you might have troubles making changes once you need to do it yourself since you won't have write permissions. That's easy enough to fix.

Comment: The error itself is going to be more related to modrewrite within your `.htaccess` since if you've moved it, you;re going to beed to point it to the right location. Probably a little beyond my help, but it wouldn't hurt to post your `.htaccess` file in your question with details on where the `codeigniter` and `wprdpress` installs are currently

Comment: codeigniter is in `public_html` folder and `wordpress` is in codeigniters `uploads` folder.  The `.htaccess` file in the `wordpress` folder i've tried deleting, changing file permissions.  But when i include `wp-load.php` in codeigniters `index.php` all my urls are changed to wordpress permalinks.

Comment: I've found out this is to do with site_url, which is defined in both wordpress and codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the `site_url` to `wp_site_url` in the wordpress folder.  Now the urls in codeigniter aren't being changed.